# Web SQL - Table is empty

Tags: sql, database, web-sql

I'm trying to create 2 tables in a web sql db and prepopulate them with some data.

My first table **category** has: `categoryID, name`.
My second table **choice** has : `id, name, checked, FK categoryID`.

This is my code:

```
var localDB = {
    init: function () {

        this.initDatabase();

        // Button and link actions
        $('#clear').on('click', function(){ 
            localDB.dropTables(); 
        });

        $('#update').on('click', function(){ 
            localDB.updateSetting(); 
        });

    },

    initDatabase: function() {
        try {
            if (!window.openDatabase) {
                alert('Local Databases are not supported by your browser. Please use a Webkit browser for this demo');
            } else {
                var shortName = 'FESTIVALDB',
                    version = '1.0',
                    displayName = 'FESIVAL DATABASE',
                    maxSize = 100000; // in bytes

                FESTIVALDB = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize);
                this.createTables();
                //this.selectAll();
            }
        } catch(e) {
            if (e === 2) {
                // Version mismatch.
                console.log("Invalid database version.");
            } else {
                console.log("Unknown error "+ e +".");
            }
            return;
        } 
    },

    /***
    **** CREATE TABLE ** 
    ***/
    createTables: function() {
        var that = this;
        FESTIVALDB.transaction(
            function (transaction) {
                // category table
                transaction.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS category(categoryID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT NOT NULL);', [], that.nullDataHandler, that.errorHandler);
            }
        );
        FESTIVALDB.transaction(
            function (transaction) {
                // choice table
                transaction.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS choice(id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT NOT NULL, checked BOOL NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, FOREIGN KEY (categoryID) REFERENCES category(categoryID));', [], that.nullDataHandler, that.errorHandler);
            }
        );

        this.prePopulate();         
    },

    /***
    **** INSERT INTO TABLE ** 
    ***/        
    prePopulate: function() {
        FESTIVALDB.transaction(
            function (transaction) {
                var categories = [];
                var choices = [];
                // CATEGORIES
                categories.push(['1','Belangrijk']);
                categories.push(['2','Toiletzak']);
                categories.push(['3','Slapen']);
                categories.push(['4','Kleren']);
                categories.push(['5','Drinken']);
                categories.push(['6','Eten']);
                categories.push(['7','Andere']);

                // CHOICES
                choices.push(['1','Toegangskaarten', 0, 1]);
                choices.push(['2','Geld', 0, 1]);

                choices.push(['3','Tandenborstel', 0, 2]);
                choices.push(['4','Tandpasta', 0, 2]);

                choices.push(['5','Tent', 0, 3]);
                choices.push(['6','Slaapzak', 0, 3]);

                choices.push(['7','Ondergoed', 0, 4]);
                choices.push(['8','Kousen', 0, 4]);

                choices.push(['9','Water', 0, 5]);
                choices.push(['10','Cola', 0, 5]);

                choices.push(['11','Koeken', 0, 6]);
                choices.push(['12','Chips', 0, 6]);

                choices.push(['13','Zakmes', 0, 7]);
                choices.push(['14','Schaar', 0, 7]);

                $.each( categories, function( index, value ){
                    transaction.executeSql("INSERT INTO category(categoryID, name) VALUES (?, ?)", [value[0], value[1]]);
                });

                $.each( choices, function( index, value ){
                    transaction.executeSql("INSERT INTO choice(id, name, checked, categoryID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", [value[0], value[1], value[2], value[3]]);
                });
            }
        );              
    };
localDB.init();
```

I don't have errors But when I check my Web SQL DB both tables are empty. What am I doing wrong?

[image]
[image]

Comment: i think you forgot one closing bracket.

Comment: Where did I forgot it? And shouldn't I get a syntax error then?

Comment: I think before localDB. Init() ;. I am still looking for error but its just an observation

Comment: Found my error, I forgot to add the categoryID twice in my choice table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My error was associated with the declaration of my Foreign Key. Instead of:

```
transaction.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS choice(id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT NOT NULL, checked BOOL NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, FOREIGN KEY (categoryID) REFERENCES category (categoryID));', [], that.nullDataHandler, that.errorHandler);
```

I had to do:

```
transaction.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS choice(id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT NOT NULL, checked BOOL NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, categoryID INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY (categoryID) REFERENCES category (categoryID));', [], that.nullDataHandler, that.errorHandler);
```